# Status bar is back (visible) when controls of videoplayer in fullscreen are shown (visible)

Tags: android, android-webview, android-video-player

I use WebView for loading a video. I overrided `onShowCustomView` (to go to fullscreen) and `onHideCustomView` (to get out of fullscreen) methods.
When I go to fullscreen mode a variable `fullscreen` is set to `true` and `OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` calls `GoFullscreen()` function that sets SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN flag and also hides Action Bar:

`decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`
`getSupportActionBar().hide();`

But when I go to fullscreen mode status bar is visible if video controls are visible. So status bar hides only if video controls are gone (not visible).

Screenshots to see a problem with controls of video and statusbar:

------------**normal** (ok)

[image: normal mode]

-----**fullscreen with video controls** (not ok)  -------- **fullscreen without video controls** (ok)
[image] [image]

Code:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private MyWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient = null;
private View mCustomView;
private LinearLayout mContentView;
private FrameLayout mCustomViewContainer;
private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
private Bundle webViewBundle;
private WebView mWebView;
private int viewWidth;
private int viewHeight;
private LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
private View decorView;
private Boolean Fullscreen = false;

private void GoFullscreen() {
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            if (Fullscreen) {
                GoFullscreen();
            } else {
                decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
                getSupportActionBar().show();
            }
        }
    });

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    viewWidth = 480;
    viewHeight = (int) (((double) viewWidth) * 0.5625); // video aspect 16:9
    layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(viewWidth, viewHeight);
    mWebView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    if (webViewBundle != null) {
        mWebView.restoreState(webViewBundle);
    } else {
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=-89326201&id=171643607&hash=2b18b090e13222dc&hd=1");
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    webViewBundle = new Bundle();
    mWebView.saveState(webViewBundle);
    mWebView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mWebView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mWebView.destroy();
}

public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
        if (mCustomView != null) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }
        Fullscreen = true;
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mContentView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        mCustomViewContainer = new FrameLayout(TestActivity.this);
        mCustomViewContainer.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
        mCustomViewContainer.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
        view.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
        mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
        mCustomView = view;
        mCustomViewCallback = callback;
        mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        GoFullscreen();
        mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setContentView(mCustomViewContainer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        if (mCustomView != null) {
            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            mCustomView = null;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewContainer = null;
            mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
            // Show the content view.
            Fullscreen = false;
            mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setContentView(mContentView);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mCustomViewContainer != null)
        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    else if (mWebView.canGoBack())
        mWebView.goBack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

How to solve it?

p.s. build.gradle API: compileSdkVersion 23 / buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" / minSdkVersion 19 / targetSdkVersion 23

**UPDATE:** seems to be problem only on KitKat. I've tested on API 23 smartphone and it doesn't have this problem. Still need to fix it for KitKat devices

Comment: check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I decided that I should not use `OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` (it would work buggy) and just call `FullscreenOn` in `onShowCustomView` and `FullscreenOff` in `onHideCustomView`. This would be working good, but still doesn't hide KitKat's sidebar fully (but works good for other versions of Android)

```
    private void FullscreenOn() {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }

    private void FullscreenOff() {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
        getSupportActionBar().show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your all stuff still same just change the FullScreen method as below and

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        }

        private void GoFullscreen() {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hello, I have this problem on KitKat (I didn't test higher API yet)

Answer (score 0):

**1. Add this theme to your styles.xml**

```
<style name="NoStatusBarTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**2. Add the above theme in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.XYZActivity"
        android:theme="@style/NoStatusBarTheme" />
```

**No deprecated code. No if-else for any specific Android version. Just one theme and DONE!!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(3846 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```